# Como enviar um dado para outra pagina PHP pela URL?

Tags: php, post

Eu sei que existe os metodos GET e POST mas nao sei como aplicá-los.

Eu possuo uma pagina chamada index.php e nela possuo diversas divs que sao geradas em um while. Quando eu clico em uma div sou redirecionado para uma pagina test.php.. como eu faço para aplicar os dados que peguei diretamente nesse link e pegá-los depois dentro da pagina `test.php?`

a forma que eu imagino seria tipo `test.php?tmpString='Teste'`
e para pegar depois no codigo nao faço ideia :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exemplo prático pelo método GET**

Esse link enviará o parâmetro pelo método GET

```
<a href="test.php?tmpString=Teste">link teste</a>
```

Para resgatar o parâmetro "tmpString" na página "test.php":

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['tmpString']))
    $tmpString = $_GET['tmpString'];
else
    $tmpString = null;

echo 'o valor de tmpString é: '.$tmpString;
```

**Exemplo prático pelo método POST**

Para enviar pelo método POST através do HTML, é preciso usar a tag `<form>`

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="tmpString" value="Teste" />
<input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Para resgatar o parâmetro "tmpString" na página "test.php":

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tmpString']))
    $tmpString = $_POST['tmpString'];
else
    $tmpString = null;

echo 'o valor de tmpString é: '.$tmpString;
```

**Nota**: Um formulário `<form>`, também pode enviar pelo método GET: `<form action="test.php" method="GET">`

Answer (score 3):

Enviando pela URL:

Teste.php?tmpString=teste

Pegando dados da URL:

```
$tmpString = $_GET['tmpString'];
```

Você ainda pode usar um if de acesso a página.

```
if($tmpString == teste {
    //  Código
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Sobre os métodos GET e POST

GET: é utilizado para pegar dados enviados pela URL, que foi o seu problema.

POST: ao utilizar ele cria uma conexão paralela para enviar os dados.

Comment: Enquanto os dados do post não são visíveis no URL, eles são bem visíveis no body do pedido `HTTP`, normalmente no formato `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (pares chave valor, tal como a query string) e por isso, não é mais seguro. A não ser que seja usado `HTTPS`

Comment: conexão paralela para o POST?

Answer (score 3):

> Eu sei que existe os metodos GET e POST mas não sei como aplicá-los.

Entender a semântica dos métodos `HTTP` é essencial para programar aplicações Web. Vou tentar explicar as diferenças entre GET e POST, mas primeiro tem que perceber os seguintes conceitos:

**Idempotente** - Algo que pode ser aplicado várias vezes, gerando sempre o mesmo resultado. Um exemplo simples é a multiplicação por 1. Pode multiplicar qualquer numero por 1 tantas vezes que quiser que vai obter sempre o número original.

**Seguro** - Um pedido é considerado seguro se não altera estado no Servidor

O método GET deve ser Indempotente e seguro, ou seja sempre que possa obter um recurso sem alterar estado, o método GET é um bom candidato.

O método POST não é nem Indempotente nem seguro, e pode ser utilizado por exemplo para alterar estado num objeto.

O método DELETE é Indempotente mas não é seguro, pode fazer um pedido para apagar um recurso tantas vezes quantas quiser que o sistema só o deve apagar 1 vez, mas altera o estado.

Portanto se o pedido que estiver a fazer à sua página teste for indempotente, seguro e pode utilizar a query string para passar os dados pode utilizar o método `GET` para o fazer.

Eu não sei PHP mas acho que o utilizador Santana deu um exemplo de como obter dados da query string.

Comment: +1 porque você disse algo que a maioria ignora e não entende que isto "é a web" (ao menos em questão de sites): *Entender a semântica dos métodos HTTP é essencial para programar aplicações Web.* Na verdade o minimo é entender o que é HTTP, requisição e resposta. Isto é algo que é o básico, mas totalmente necessário saber.