# Por que o método GET é considerado seguro e o método POST inseguro? E em que situações devo usá-los?

Tags: rest, http, post, get

Li que o método `GET` é considerado "seguro" e o método `POST` é considerado "inseguro". Não deveria ser o contrário? O método `POST` não expõe na URL os dados enviados, por isso não deveria ser considerado "seguro"?

Em que situações devo utilizar o método `GET` e o método `POST`?

Não é mais vantajoso utilizar sempre o `POST` já que o `GET` possui mais limitações, como por exemplo, o limite de caracteres?

Comment: [Pode ser útil.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info)

Comment: Eu já ouvi falar o contrário: Que `GET` é inseguro e `POST` é seguro. A segurança depende também de quem programa, independente do método.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não é o que diz a especificação e eu de certa forma concordo. O POST é considerado seguro porque é utilizado de forma incorreta, mas acredito que quem criou a especificação (que é onde a resposta se baseia) não se equivocou.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP, e qual é a diferença entre eles?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9419/quais-s%c3%a3o-os-m%c3%a9todos-de-requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-http-e-qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-eles)

Comment: @Bacco não concordo com a duplicata, embora sejam assuntos idênticos, não são tratados da mesma forma. A resposta é completamente diferente da pergunta marcada como duplicata, inclusive cheguei a ver essas questões antes de postar essa.

Comment: Fiquei em dúvida de fechar como duplicata daquela, ou dessa: [Quando devo usar função GET e quando devo usar função POST?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118213) - E teve mais coisa recente falando disso. Lembre-se de que nada impede de você postar algo lá que complemente as respostas existentes.

Comment: @Bacco continuo não concordando com você, aqui a questão é porque um é considerado seguro e outro inseguro de acordo com a especificação, porque o que temos é o contrário. A questão de quando devo usar um o outro foi uma parte para complementar a resposta.

Comment: Tem mais uma que fala disso, só de curiosidade :) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106507/70 (não resisti deixar de linkar, só por causa do _idempotente_) Como complemento, essa é legal, falando de PUT e POST: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92870/

Answer (score 3):

Vejo muitas respostas explicando quando devemos utilizar o método `GET` e quando utilizar o método `POST` do protocolo HTTP e basicamente as respostas se resumem a explicar vantagens e desvantagens de cada método o que culmina na escolha do `POST` como o métodos mais seguro.

Geralmente utilizamos o método `POST` nos formulários para comunicar com o servidor, não importa se a ação terá "efeitos colaterais" ou não. Simplesmente fazemos assim aparentemente sem motivo algum ou pela primícia de que o `POST` é mais seguro.

Mas será que isso é verdade?

Se você ler o [RFC do HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1), irá descobrir que o método `GET` é descrito como "seguro". Seguro, no contexto do HTTP, significa que você deveria ser capaz de fazer vários GET's para uma aplicação web e isso não deveria causar efeitos colaterais, como apagar uma notícia, ele não deve causar alterações no recurso que está sendo requisitado, porque toda a ideia do método `GET` é de que você deveria simplesmente receber uma cópia do recurso que está naquela URL específica. Você não está fazendo nada de especial com o recurso, você deveria ser capaz de recebê-lo em qualquer lugar e a qualquer momento que desejasse.

Entretanto, lendo a descrição do método `POST`, você irá descobrir que ele é um método "inseguro". Se você envia um `POST` pra uma URL, você pode estar definitivamente alterando algo no servidor e causando efeitos colaterais indesejáveis. Ou você pode simplesmente estar criando um novo recurso, como por exemplo, um post de blog.

A diferença óbvia é que o `POST` pode (e normalmente deve) alterar o estado de alguma coisa do lado do servidor, enquanto um `GET` nunca deveria ser capaz de fazer o mesmo. Comparando com bancos de dados que usam `SQL`, GETs seriam como "selects" e POSTs como "inserts". Você já viu algum "insert" que retorna uma tabela de resultados ou um "select" que insere dados no banco?

Mas é claro que tudo ainda pode ficar pior. Imagine que você é o dono de um site que usa apenas `POST` em todos os seus formulários e um desses é um formulário de pesquisa. Utilizadores irão utiliza-lo para buscar produtos e adicioná-los ao seu carrinho de compra. Imagine que o utilizador está interessado em comprar um determinado produto, mas ele não tem a certeza do nome, então ele simplesmente digita algo e aperta "enter" no teclado (ou no botão enviar)...

Lá está!

Aparece uma lista de produtos. Ele clica no primeiro e descobre que não era o pretendido, então pensa o incauto utilizador: "Vou apertar no botão voltar e procurar pelo produto no restante da lista...”, e quando ele clica no botão, o navegador mostra uma mensagem interessante:

> O navegador precisa enviar dados para o servidor para executar esta ação. Você tem certeza que deseja fazer isso?

Como protocolo HTTP define, o método `POST` não é um método "seguro" e as ferramentas - normalmente os navegadores - devem avisar o utilizador de que alguma coisa ruim pode acontecer se ele tentar enviar um `POST` por acidente em uma página. E é exatamente isso que acontece ao tentar clicar no botão voltar após um `POST`. Nesse exemplo, o utilizador não estaria fazendo nada de errado, mas imagine se em vez de estar voltando pra uma página de busca, ele poderia estar voltando para o formulário de "adicionar cliente" e um "voltar" poderia muito bem fazer com que o novo cliente fosse recriado no banco de dados, o que não seria a intenção do utilizador.

Pior, se você está usando `POST` em um formulário de busca, os usuários nunca vão poder usar o botão voltar (os mestres da usabilidade dizem que ele é a coisa mais usada nos navegadores) e eles também não vão poder colocar aquela página de resultado nos seus favoritos! Você consegue imaginar algo pior do que isso? Você está evitando que as pessoas possam expressar todo o seu amor pelo seu site postando links pra eles no del.icio.us!

A ideia é simples, se você não está alterando nada no servidor, você deveria sempre usar `GET`, seja lá o que for. Ele não quebra o botão voltar ou atualizar, deixa o utilizador adicionar as páginas requisitadas nos favoritos e não vai fazer com que os navegadores mostrem mensagens assustadoras para os utilizadores.

Se você estiver alterando o estado de alguma coisa no servidor, você deve usar o `POST` (e os outros métodos do HTTP que são definidos como "inseguros", como PUT e DELETE), requisições que usam `GET` **NUNCA** deveriam alterar recursos no servidor (sabe aquele link que você fez que apaga um registro no banco de dados? Foi uma péssima ideia!).

Você deve estar se perguntando: "Então devo enviar os dados do login via `GET`, uma vez que não estou alterando nenhum recurso no servidor?"

Eu respondo com outra pergunta: a autenticação/autorização não altera o estado do utilizador dentro da aplicação?

Comment: É uma tradução livre do http://blog.codevader.com/2008/11/02/why-learning-http-does-matter/ embora de 2008, muito atual.