# Uma dúvida em relação ao uso de POST na comunicação entre Javascript/AJAX e PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

Pois bem estou trabalhando num projeto que liga o JS ao PHP através do AJAX. Para fazer essa conexão estava usando o método GET e ai fazia a requisição dessa forma: `"seilaooque.php?valor1=x&valor2=y"`

só que agora to pensando em passar tudo pra POST. Mas a minha dúvida é mesmo sendo em POST poderei mandar os comandos dessa forma `"valor1=x&valor2=y"` ou vou ter que mandar um valor de cada vez através do método `XMLHTTP.send()?`

Comment: GET e POST não tem diferenças podendo se dizer, a diferença é que GET é mais rápido e POST mais seguro

Comment: Sim Victor. Mas o parâmetro é o mesmo?

Comment: possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106500/como-enviar-um-dado-para-outra-pagina-php-pela-url

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o POST, seu ajax ficaria assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'suapage.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {var1: "var", var2: "var2", var3: "var3"}, //dados enviados via POST
    success: function(e) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Valeu Prisley mas nesse caso eu não to usando o Jquery. Eu estou trabalhando apenas com Javascript. Mas mesmo assim obrigado pelo esclarecimento.